# Ruby on Rails Inline around_save Callback Yields a LocalJumpError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback, ruby-1.9

In Rails 3.0.5 & Ruby 1.9.3, is it possible to define the body of an `around_save` callback inline with the `around_save` declaration?

That is, I've noticed that this case works properly:

```
around_save :around_save_body
def around_save_body
  puts 'before save'
  yield 
  puts 'after save'
end

[114] pry(main)> a = Activity.find(57)
=> #<Activity id: 57, ... >

[115] pry(main)> a.save
before save
after save
=> true
```

Whereas if I put the body inline, I get a LocalJumpError:

```
around_save do |activity|
  puts 'before save'
  yield 
  puts 'after save'
end

[117] pry(main)> a = Activity.find(57)
=> #<Activity id: 57, ... >

[118] pry(main)> a.save
before save
LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)
from /home/maksim/hkn/website/app/models/activity.rb:47:in `block in <class:Activity>'
```

I tried changing `yield` to `yield activity` in the second example, but I got the same result. Is it possible to have my `around_save` body be inline with the `around_save` declaration?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this case `ActiveRecord` will pass a `Proc` as a second argument, simply do this:

```
around_save do |activity, block|
  puts 'before save'
  block.call
  puts 'after save'
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Could you please point me towards where that syntax is documented (or is it learned by reading the source)?

Comment: Sadly, I can't find an appropriate place that I could directly point you to. That was a trial-and-error, as I just suspect that Ruby would make the passed-in block as second argument because of the way that you can `yield` in the defined callback method. The callback stuff in Rails is confusing, but you can find them here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/callbacks.rb and https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb

Comment: I did some more testing and even though that runs, I'm not sure if it produces the right result. Here is a more comprehensive example showing my actual vs expected output: http://pastie.org/4242079. Do you have any more advice possibly? Am I misunderstanding how this callback should work?

Comment: Yep, the result you're seeing is the expected result. At the time that callback runs, the value should be set to 4 already. The only one way to be able to detect the previous value is to use `ActiveModel::Dirty` (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) methods such as `point_was`, `point_change` to get the value before it was set.

Comment: I see that this is able to track attributes changing, but `points_squared` is an instance method. Is there a way to track an instance method's change, since I don't think that I can call `_was` or `_change` on it? Or do I have to save it to an attribute?

Comment: I think the best and easiest way is to actually track change of `points` and maybe create a method name `previous_points_squared` that squared `points_was`. That way, you wouldn't have to deal with a stale variable or single use attribute.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Thanks! I simplified my example from the actual case but I can apply your idea to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Still in 2015 it's hard to find documentation on this (or maybe my google skilz are bad...)